# Akka2.1/Scala - Nodes created in actor do not show up in context.children?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an abstract class that is an actor and it has a method like this

```
def getNewConnection(id: String): ActorRef

A class that subclasses it defines the method.

  override def getNewConnection(id: String): ActorRef = {
    val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new RsvpClusterableClientConnection(service, id)))
    actorRef ! Subscribe(clientConnectionId)
    actorRef
  }
```

And then it stores that actorRef.

The thing is, when I go context.children it's empty.
Similarly if the child actor goes context.parent ! "HEY!" the parent won't get the message.
If I look at the path, the context.partent shows /users/ and the REAL parent actor is actually something like /users/$2b

I can't find anyone with similar issues.
This is in a test that goes something like this:

```
class ZombieTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("zombietest")) with HelperSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
[...]
val conActor = system.actorOf(Props(new ConnectionActor(testService1)))
}
```

EDIT

AgileSteel is correct. creating from system will create a top level actor. Creating from context will create a child.

From akka documentation:

> Creating Actors with default constructor

```
object Main extends App {  
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")   val myActor =
system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor") The call to actorOf
```

> returns an instance of ActorRef. This is a handle to the Actor
>   instance which you can use to interact with the Actor. The ActorRef is
>   immutable and has a one to one relationship with the Actor it
>   represents. The ActorRef is also serializable and network-aware. This
>   means that you can serialize it, send it over the wire and use it on a
>   remote host and it will still be representing the same Actor on the
>   original node, across the network.
>
> In the above example the actor was created from the system. It is also
>   possible to create actors from other actors with the actor context.
>   The difference is how the supervisor hierarchy is arranged. When using
>   the context the current actor will be supervisor of the created child
>   actor. When using the system it will be a top level actor, that is
>   supervised by the system (internal guardian actor).

```
class FirstActor extends Actor {   val myActor =
context.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should/must call `actorOf` on `context` instead of `system` when creating children.

Comment: I’d replace SHOULD with MUST ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I missed that in the documentation. I'll edit my post with a quote from the docs.